# Can't enable Google+ API

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-developers-console

Today I try to enable Google+ API on [API Manager](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/plus/overview?project=store-client-ids) and it said

> Error: failed to do requirement checks

What wrong? I just disable it and I want to re-enable again.

[image]

Comment: wow that's different.

Comment: it is working for me now

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely an outage on [Google Developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/) even though I am not seeing it on the [status](http://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=da&v=status) page.

There for the fastest way to get it resolved will be to go to the upper right hand corner in google developer console look for the !.  Send feed back.

[image]

You cant feed back the actually error as its a popup but you can feed back from the screen before you attempt to enable an error.

Comment: I'm beginner to use google developer console, Thank you for your suggestion :)

Comment: It seams its back up now.   Most of Googles pages have a feedback link.   Google normally has people monitoring things so you can get pretty quick response using feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem.  Perhaps it is an outage.

Evidence:  I count 5 people here so far that have the issue, and no google results for that exact error message.  "Error: failed to do requirement checks"  That means, it's a new error, and google's crawler hasn't had time to scrape even this question yet.

Comment: Suddenly 3 people have the same problem, smells of an outage, regardless of whether it's a reported outage.

Comment: I am trying to find someone to report it to but this is bad time for Google if memory services the Google+ team is in mountain view they are all asleep.     Sent out a random scatter email to a couple of people

Comment: I am sure there is an oncall.

Comment: My contacts aren't that extensive I will post back if I hear anything back.

Comment: I've got the same issue when attempting to enable Custom Search API.

Comment: I've got the same issue trying to enable any API. Definitely smells of outage.

Answer (score 1):

It's okay now, I just re-enabling the API and it works.
I think its outage